# How to hide/close entire options list of HTML <select> element programatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of HTML `<select>` elements, and want the *entire* `<options>` dropdown to close/hide when the mouse moves somewhere else. Is there a plain JavaScript solution? (The next can of worms I might try is sending an ESC keystroke to the `<select>` element...)

Note 1: I do not want to hide individual options from the list - that question has plenty answers meanwhile.
Note 2: As a purist and avoider of accidental complexity I do not use/need jQuery - but here might possibly be a reason to reconsider?

Comment: Perhaps you could dispatch the Blur event on mouseout?

Comment: @mykaf No, this doesn't work on Firefox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of what mykaf proposed, this will close the select on mouseleave

```js
document.querySelector('select').onmouseleave = function(){this.blur();}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="a">Option A</option>
  <option value="b">Option B</option>
  <option value="c">Option C</option>
  <option value="d">Option D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Implemented, works, and even solved another small issue. I've never seen blur() mentioned in all the docu.

Comment: On **Firefox**, How can you do to select `Option C` ? I try it, but it is always `Option A` !

Comment: Oh, indeed it doesn't work on Firefox! Try putting the blur() in a setTimout(...).

Comment: function(){ setTimeout( ()=>{this.blur();}, 1); } (Can't log in on FF to edit/test code snippet.)

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know about Firefox